# Internet connection troubles

Tags: raspbian, wifi

We are trying to use our Raspberry Pi B+ but we have to connect it to the internet. What we want is to use a Wi-Fi dongle to connect it but that won't work.

We then tried to connect it with a Ethernet cable but it won't allow us to connect either.

Any solutions would be great.

Comment: Can you plug your ethernet cable and post the result of `ifconfig` command ?

Comment: Yeah here http://imgur.com/a/bedPn

Comment: You've left out important parts of ifconfig's output: the interface names. However, as wlan0 clearly is missing your USB Wifi dongle isn't supported. I suggest getting the semi-official EdiMax 2.4GHz adapter or the official Raspberry Foundation Dongle. Next, your Ethernet isn't connect, as there is no CARRIER indication, no TX packets ever sent. Please plug in your cable into the Pi and into your home router/whatever, wait several seconds, then check ifconfig. At least you should now see an IPv4 address, even if it's only a 169.254.x.x.

Comment: We plugged in the Ethernet when we ran this command. And if we're reading this correctly, we should get a dongle that is supported by this Pi?

Comment: Also how are we supposed to get the interface names? What was in that screenshot was the entire output of ifconfig.